# Ruby - Copy image from different server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using an api that has a list of images that I would like to save to my own server. Does anyone have any suggestions on what are the best ways of doing this? or what lib's I should be looking to use?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby's open-uri library is a quick way to get going.

[open-uri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html)

It extends the open method with support for urls, so the following works:

```
require 'open-uri'

File.open("out.png", "w") {|o|
  open("http://www.example.com/some.png") {|f|
    o.write( f.read )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Standard_Library/Net::HTTP